# jquery upgrading makes some things stop working

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, scroll

Hi could you help me out here - I'm currently working on this site: [Look here](http://mediemaskinen.dk), the only thing i can't seem to figure out is why my scroll inside div's wont work if i use jQuery 1.9 or above, but if i use 1.6.1 the div scroll is working great. It's running on my 1.6.1 now, so its working - But then under the page "Priser" if you scroll down, the clear it all button (Ryd alt) isn't working. The button is simply not clickable.

The script used for scroll is:
     // scroll

```
 $('.scroll').cScroll({
    duration:700,
    step:63,
    trackCl:'track',
    shuttleCl:'shuttle'
 });
```

Is that script useable with jQuery 1.9?

The script for the clearing of the drag and drop items looks like this, as i said, clearing these items from the dropping box doesn't seem to work in jQuery 1.6.1.

```
    $("#btn_clear").click(function() {
        $("#cart_items").fadeOut("2000", function() {
           $(this).html("").fadeIn("fast").css({left: 0});
        });
        $("#citem").html("0");
        $("#cprice").html("DKK 0,-");
        total_items = 0;
        total_price = 0;
        return false;
    });
```

Can't seem to figure out what to do, or how to make both things work with jQuery 1.9

Comment: most likely the plugin is using $.browser. Check your console for errors.

Comment: And try using the jQuery Migrate plugin. It was developed to help you switch to the newer version.

Comment: The weird thing is that this is working at my stationairy computer (Windows - using chrome) - But it aint working on my mac (MacOS - Chrome) - anyone able to figure that out?

Comment: Kevin B - There isn't any errors other than mising image files to detect in my console.